# Right way of placing interestitial ad in ionic android platform

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, admob

For showing interestitial ad in my android app (which i have made using ionic) i have used the following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function runads(){
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function initAds() {
if (admob) {
  var adPublisherIds = {
    ios : {
      banner : "###############",
      interstitial : "##################"
    },
    android : {
      banner : "#############",
      interstitial : "#########################"
    }
  };

  var admobid = (/(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? adPublisherIds.android : adPublisherIds.ios;

  admob.setOptions({
    publisherId:      admobid.banner,
    interstitialAdId: admobid.interstitial,
    tappxIdiOs:       "/XXXXXXXXX/Pub-XXXX-iOS-IIII",
    tappxIdAndroid:   "/XXXXXXXXX/Pub-XXXX-Android-AAAA",
    tappxShare:       0.5
  });

  registerAdEvents();

} else {
  alert('AdMobAds plugin not ready');
}
}

 function onAdLoaded(e) {
if (e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE.INTERSTITIAL) {
  admob.showInterstitialAd();
  showNextInterstitial = setTimeout(function() {
    admob.requestInterstitialAd();
  }, 2 * 60 * 1000); // 2 minutes
}
}

 // optional, in case respond to events
 function registerAdEvents() {
document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdLoaded, onAdLoaded);
document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdFailedToLoad, function (e) {});
document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdOpened, function (e) {});
document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdClosed, function (e) {});
document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdLeftApplication, function (e) {});
document.addEventListener(admob.events.onInAppPurchaseRequested, function (e) {});
}

function onDeviceReady() {
document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
initAds();

// display a banner at startup
admob.createBannerView();

// request an interstitial
admob.requestInterstitialAd();
}
```

My interestitial ad is showing perfectly using this code.Then, i have uploaded it in google play store.suddenly i have got a message from google Admob team regarding interestitial ad placing . The message is -

> Hello,We are alerting you that your app is currently in violation of the AdMob program policies. Importantly, this will require action on your part to ensure no disruption in ad serving. Please read below for more information on the actions you need to take:
>
> Violation explanation
>
> LAYOUT ENCOURAGES ACCIDENTAL CLICKS - INTERSTITIAL ADS:Publishers are not permitted to encourage users to click AdMob interstitial ads in any way. Please review how you’ve implemented interstitial ads and be mindful of the following non-compliant implementation(s):Interstitial ads that load unexpectedly while a user is viewing the app’s content.For more information about our policies and tips for how to comply please read the following:
>
> Interstitial ads that load unexpectedly while a user is viewing the app’s content.For more information about our policies and tips for how to comply please read the following:AdMob ad placement policyAdMob interstitial ad guidanceAdMob preload instructions for Android and iOSAction required: Please make changes immediately to your app to comply with AdMob program policies.Current account status: ActiveYou do not need to contact us once you've made the necessary changes to your app. Please be aware that if additional violations are accrued, ad serving may be disabled to the app listed above.Note that the app listed above is just one example and the same violation may exist on other apps you own. We suggest that you review all your apps for compliance with the AdMob program policies to reduce the likelihood of future warnings.For more information regarding our policy warning notifications, visit our Help Center.Thank you for your cooperation.Sincerely,The Google AdMob Team

How Can i solve this problem ?

Comment: What does your app do? They are basically saying that you're popping interstitial add out of nowhere, making users click on it accidentally while browsing contents of your app. So for example if you developed a game, you would place an interstitial add when user pauses the game, not in the middle of the playing

Comment: My app is simple informative type.i am new in ionic.I don't actually understand in which section i should edit in ad code (given in the post) which will help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: You could either figure out a way when to display interstitial. Like, prepare in the background and show when some page or state change. Or, get rid of the interstitial and only keep the banners. Check this https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/wiki/1.4-Methods-for-Interstitial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what is going on is that the loading of an interstitial ad takes some time, so you need to plan the loading of an interstitial and ensure the interstitial is available when you need to show it. If not, launching `admob.showInterstitialAd()` will load the interstital and show it when it is available (as the flag `autoShowInterstitial` is `true` by default, see https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/setOptions).

There is a complete example on how to plan the interstitials: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/showInterstitialAd.

Basically what you do is to request an interstitial and let the app know if the interstitial is available or not. Probably your code for ionic should look like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['admobModule'])

    .constant('AdmobConfig', {
        bannerId: /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ? "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/ANDROID_BANNER_ID" : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IOS_BANNER_ID",
        interstitialId: /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ? "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/ANDROID_INTERSTITIAL_ID" : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IOS_INTERSTITIAL_ID",
    })

    .config(function (admobSvcProvider, AdmobConfig) {
        admobSvcProvider.setOptions({
            publisherId: AdmobConfig.bannerId,
            interstitialAdId: AdmobConfig.interstitialId,
            autoShowInterstitial: false,
        });
    })

    .run(function ($rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $timeout, admobSvc) {
        admobSvc.requestInterstitialAd();

        $rootScope.isInterstitialAvailable = false;
        $rootScope.isAppForeground = false;

        $rootScope.$on(admobSvc.events.onAdLoaded, function onAdLoaded(evt, e) {
            if ($rootScope.isAppForeground) {
                if (e.adType === admobSvc.AD_TYPE.INTERSTITIAL) {
                    $rootScope.isInterstitialAvailable = true;
                }
            }
        });

        $rootScope.$on(admobSvc.events.onAdOpened, function onAdOpened(evt, e) {
            if ($rootScope.isAppForeground) {
                if (e.adType === admobSvc.AD_TYPE.INTERSTITIAL) {
                    $rootScope.isInterstitialAvailable = false;
                    $timeout(admobSvc.requestInterstitialAd, 1); // Immediately request next interstitial asap
                }
            }
        });

        $ionicPlatform.on('pause', function onPause() {
            if ($rootScope.isAppForeground) {
                $rootScope.isAppForeground = false;
            }
        });
        $ionicPlatform.on('resume', function onResume() {
            if (!$rootScope.isAppForeground) {
                $timeout(admobSvc.requestInterstitialAd, 1);
                $rootScope.isAppForeground = true;
            }
        });
    })

    .controller('YourController', function ($rootScope, admobSvc) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.pleaseShowInterstitial = function () {
            if ($rootScope.isInterstitialAvailable) {
                admobSvc.showInterstitialAd();
            }
        };
    });
```

Also note that there is a management for foreground app. This is important as if not, the user could put the app in background and the interstitial would automatically be shown. In your case it is not so relevant, as you control when the interstitial is shown, but I recommend you to keep this, in case you decide to start auto showing interstitials :)